# VBA Word inputting into nested cells

Tags: vba, ms-word

Im looking to input text into nested cells in word using VBA. I can input into the top level table using the code below but can't input into a nested cell. (There are multiple nested tables).

Any help on how to do this?

ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(Row:=23, Column:=19).Range.Text = ""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to test for nested cells and then point to the appropriate cell range. Here is an example.

```
If Selection.Cells(1).NestingLevel = 2 Then
    Selection.Cells(1).Range.Cells(1).Range.Text = "Nested"
Else
    Selection.Cells(1).Range.Text = "Not Nested"
End If
```

Using your example of a table that contains a nested table cell in Row 23, Column 19 the command will look like the following.

```
ActiveDocument.Tables(1).Cell(23, 19).Range.Cells(1).Range.Text = "123"
```

I want to emphasize though that you should test that there is actually a nested cell within the given cell range. If you don't, your code could fail.

Comment: That works well for selecting the cells which I will be able to use in my next project. How would I go about adapting that to autofill a cell from a macro? say select the 3rd cell in the nested table and type "123"? Thanks

Comment: @BradleySmith, I have added an example that hopefully now answers your question.

Comment: That's sorted the problem. Cheers :)